# Handling Data on PostgreSQL for a comment thread app similar to Reddit

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

First time posting a question on here.

I am working with PostgreSQL and had a question on how to format data coming from a PostgreSQL DB.  For practice, I am building a comment thread app similar to Reddit's.  I organized my database in the following way

**Post Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Posts (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
userId int,
header VARCHAR
)
```

**Comment Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Comments (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
userId int,
commentText VARCHAR,
parentId int,
postId int
)
```

I want my end data to be an array of objects organized by postId with a comments key / value pair that stores all the comments for that postId (example below).

Should I format my data in this way using postgres queries, run sorting server side, or on client side? AND is this a conventional/efficient way of handling/formatting this kind of data? or am I missing some other way of organizing data for a comment thread?

Im use to working with MongoDb so not sure if my way of wanting to structure the data is due to working with mongoDb.

I would like for my data to look somewhat like this (unless there is a better more efficient way of doing it):

```
const posts = [
 {
   postId: 1, 
   header: 'Post Header', 
   comments: [
              {
                commentId: 1, 
                text: 'comment text',
                parentId: null
              }, 
              {
                commentId: 2, 
                text: 'comment text',
                parentId: 1
              }
            ]

 },
 {
   postId: 2, 
   header: 'Post Header', 
   comments: [
              {
                commentId: 3, 
                text: 'comment text',
                parentId: null
              }, 
              {
                commentId: 2, 
                text: 'comment text',
                parentId: 3
              }
            ]
 },
]
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Do you want the SQL statement to return a JSON result? How do you want comments on comments to be included in the result? The `posts` table seems unnecessary though. A post header is essentially a comment without a `parentid`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for the response! Yes, I would like the result to be JSON. I was imagining connecting comments of comments by parentId (updated the json results in my post a bit) but honestly having a hard time picturing what the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has a number of built-in ways to handle JSON: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Something like

```
SELECT
   postID
   ,json_build_array(
      json_build_object('commentId', id, 'text', commentText, 'parentId', parentId)
    ) as comments
FROM comments
GROUP BY postId
```

and then just join to the original `Posts` for metadata